# Corrupt VirtualBox VDI

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vdi

I've got a Ubuntu 15.10 64bit Guest on a Windows Host. Today when I wanted to start the VM I got the message "FATAL: no bootable medium found! System halted."

I checked, that the VDI is correctly linked and that the virtual DVD tray is empty.

[image: screenshot of mass storage]

I also recreated a new VM which used a copy of the VDI as Harddrive. The only odd thing I noticed is the actual size of the image that is shown:

Virtual size: 14.47 GB

actual size: 2.00 MB

Windows Explorer unfortunately also tells me that the image is about 2MB. What could have happened to my VM?

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of your VM's settings > Storage.

Comment: I attached a screenshot in the op [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xM1pE.png)

Comment: You did not make any changes to the VM before it started doing this?

Comment: @JosephA. no, I didn't

Comment: Are you OK losing the data originally on the machine?

Comment: yes I am. It's just a VM for testing purposes. It just bothers me that the VM suddenly is unusable. Would be even worse, if the data was important.

Comment: I have a guess that perhaps this has been caused by the guest OS (Ubuntu in this case) in the VM. Perhaps something occurred (virus, prank, etc) that caused the OS to remove all data on the VM, **including the boot partition**. 

This is perhaps why you cannot boot the machine, "no bootable medium found". The next step would be to recreate the machine and be more careful next time.

As to the actual reason for the data loss, I cannot be sure.